# Как исправить баг у сборки gulp?

Tags: gulp, sass, gulp-sass

Всем привет!

У меня есть gulp-стартер, который я доработал под себя, взяв за основу html_optimized4.
Посмотреть сборку можно тут (сделал публичной, только чтобы задать вопрос) - https://github.com/feodoraxis/FStartHTML

Сама проблема:
Постоянно, когда я пытаюсь сохранить файл sass, у меня через раз получается такая ошибка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJfXC.png

Или, например, когда я пытаюсь написать что-то вроде этого (файл sass/common/config/_base.sass)

```
$maxW1: 1364px
.wrapper
  margin: 0 auto 
  max-width: $maxW1
  position: relative
  padding: .1px 50px
    +xl() 
      padding: .1px 20px
```

Получается такое:

```
.wrapper { 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  margin-max-width: 1364px; 
  margin-position: relative; 
  padding: .1px 50px; }
```

Как вообще с этим бороться? Может есть какие-то правила создания таких сборок, которых я просто не знаю?

Answer (score 0):

Опытным путём выяснилось следующее: ошибка возникает в следствие того, что препроцессор не может получить файл в тот момент, когда происходит его сохранение. А обратиться к этому файлу он пытается мгновенно.

Я нашел два практических решения проблемы:
- Используем SSD. Файл быстрее сохраняется, препроцессор получает его во-время.
- Используем "gulp-changed"